# python multiple and simultaneous fifo

Tags: python

How can I open multiple fifo's with Python3 ?
The code below is quite simple but it stacks at last line and wait for(?)...
Please any help ?

```
   toAgent = ['ABCD', 'EFGH', 'IJKL', 'MNOP',]

   def createPipe():

        for i in range(0, len(toAgent)):
            #print(i)
            fifoName = '../tmp/' + toAgent[i]       
            if not os.path.exists(fifoName):
                os.mkfifo(fifoName) 

                pipeName = 'pipe_' + str(i)
                print(pipeName, fifoName)
                pipeName = os.open(fifoName, os.O_WRONLY )
```

Comment: Your function is wrong, and you aren't calling the function

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
toAgent = ['ABCD', 'EFGH', 'IJKL', 'MNOP',]

def createPipe():
    for i in range(0, len(toAgent)):
            #print(i)
        fifoName = '../tmp/' + toAgent[i]
        if not os.path.exists(fifoName):
            os.mkfifo(fifoName)

            pipeName = 'pipe_' + str(i)
            print(pipeName, fifoName)
            pipeName = os.open(fifoName, os.O_WRONLY )

createPipe()
```

Comment: The function createPipe() creates only 1 pipe and not 4 as per toAgent[] contents. It will wait in a loop forever(?) between each pipe creation. The only way I found is break the loop with CTRL-C than send a new python3.